# C# WPF - ListView item to TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

So I have this class

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public string ID { get; set; }
}
```

And my window has this ListView called "**lvUsers**" and a label called "**label**"

```
<ListView Margin="10,10,237,10" Name="lvUsers" SelectionChanged="idk">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>

<Label x:Name="label" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="380,130,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Then I assigned the items like this

```
public static List<User> users = new List<User>();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    users.Add(new User() { Name = "John", Age = 42, ID = "H42"});
    users.Add(new User() { Name = "Jacob", Age = 39, ID = "H39"});
    users.Add(new User() { Name = "Richard", Age = 28, ID = "H28"});

    lvUsers.ItemsSource = users;
}
```

**And my question is:** Is there a possibility that when I click an item in the ListView, the item's **ID** property will be displayed in a label called "**label**".

What I mean is that when I click on an item that says **John** and **42**, I want **label** to say **H42**.

Is there a way to do it? Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a neat binding:

```
<Label Content="{Binding SelectedItem.ID, ElementName=lvUsers}" ...
```

You can also extend this to add a string format.

```
{Binding SelectedItem.ID, ElementName=lvUsers, StringFormat={}H{0}}
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be much easier to use bindings, but I can see that you are using events:
`SelectionChanged="idk"` in `ListView`.
So in your code behind of window there must have (or compile-time error will occur) the method:

```
private void idk(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
```

So you can add some code to that `idk`:

```
private void idk(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // your code

    if (e.AddedItems.Count != 1) 
    {
        return; // or sth else
    }

    var selectedUser = (User)e.AddedItems[0];
    this.label.Text = selectedUser.ID;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd just handle SelectionChanged event:

```
<ListView Margin="10,154,237,10" Name="lvUsers" SelectionChanged="lvUsers_SelectionChanged">
```

like this:

```
    private void lvUsers_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        User u = (User)lvUsers.SelectedItem;
        this.label.Content = u.ID;
    }
```